# MultiSelect = FALSE Doesn't Work on LISTVIEW

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0

Language :: Visual C++ Windows Form Application
Platform :: VS 2008 (.Net 4.0)

I am using the Checked ListView control.  I have the "MultiSelect" option set to FALSE.  This seems to work to only allow one row at a time to be highlighted.

What doesn't seem to be working though is the Check box associated with each item in the ListView.  Even with "MultiSelect" = FALSE it is still allowing the user to check more than one item in the list.

I understand the basic premis behind the CheckBox . . . That it allows more than one item to be selected.  But, is there any way around this "feature"?  Is there any way to limit only one item checked in a Checked ListView even with the "MultiSelect" option = FALSE?

I am desperate.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix could be to un-select all existing items before selecting the new one.

Comment: The following code works nicely, Thank you "McMinton"        System::Void lstEmpleadoAutos_ItemCheck(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::ItemCheckEventArgs^  e)
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < this->lstEmpleadoAutos->Items->Count ; i++)
            {
                if (i != e->Index)
                {
                    this->lstEmpleadoAutos->Items[i]->Checked = false ;
                    this->lstEmpleadoAutos->Items[i]->Selected = false ;
                }
            }

            this->lstEmpleadoAutos->Items[e->Index]->Selected = true ;
        }